# Click a button and be directed to new activity, Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**MainActivity.Java**

```
package com.example.drexsprint.login;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
        Button b1,b2;
        EditText ed1,ed2;

        TextView tx1;
        int counter = 3;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
            ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
            ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

            b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
            tx1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            tx1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(ed1.getText().toString().equals("admin") &&

                            ed2.getText().toString().equals("1234")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Credentials",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        tx1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        tx1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        counter--;
                        tx1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));

                        if (counter == 0) {
                            b1.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Arduino Security"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="#ff7aff24"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:hint="Enter Name"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textColorHighlight="#ff7eff15"
        android:textColorHint="#ffff25e6"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />



    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText"
        android:textColorHint="#ffff299f"
        android:hint="Password" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Attempts Left:"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="login"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="#ddec0d"
        android:background="#0e17c2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#df0c0c"
        android:textColor="#0dca07"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Please Login:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Second Screen App**

**screen.Java**

```
package com.example.drexsprint.login;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;



public class Screen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    public void Left(View view) {

        myWebView.loadUrl("http://admin:0000000AA@10.0.1.16/?button2");
    }

    public void Right (View view) {

        myWebView.loadUrl("http://admin:0000000AA@10.0.1.16/?button3");
    }

    public void Temp (View view) {

        myWebView.loadUrl("http://admin:0000000AA@10.0.1.16/?button1");
    }

    public void Hum (View view) {

        myWebView.loadUrl("http://admin:0000000AA@10.0.1.16/button1");
    }

    public void Photo (View view) {
        goToUrl("http://admin:0000000AA@10.0.1.6/image.jpg");
    }

    private void goToUrl(String url) {
        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
        startActivity(launchBrowser);
        /** public void Photo (View view) {

         // myWebView.loadUrl("http://admin:0000000AA@10.0.1.6/image.jpg");
         }**/

    }}
```

**screen_layout**

```
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rotate Left"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="Left"
        android:backgroundTint="#0f50e8"
        android:textColor="#f4d318"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rotate Right"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="Right"
        android:backgroundTint="#0f50e8"
        android:textColor="#f4d318"
        android:layout_below="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Temp."
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:onClick="Temp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:backgroundTint="#369d7c"
        android:textColor="#f4d318" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Hum."
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:onClick="Hum"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:backgroundTint="#369d7c"
        android:textColor="#f4d318" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Take Photo"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:onClick="Photo"
        android:backgroundTint="#589d36"
        android:textColor="#f4d318"
        android:layout_below="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/webView"
        android:background="#0a0a0a"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contextClickable="true"
        android:focusable="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Okay! So I got two aplications, the first one is a login screen and the second one is a main menu of what the application should do, I want to find a way so that when a user insert the correct credentials and click on the Login button the app executes the second screen the main menu, how can i do this, Join the two apps together.

[image: This is the first app, login screen]

[image: And this is the main menu App]

Wat i wanna achieve is on the the click of "Login Button" on the first app it Launches the Second app as a window! Thanks!! Kind  of new in android any detailed help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You got 2 apps, or 2 activities in 1 app?

Comment: Why don't you merge the two apps into one using different activities and then use an intent to go from one activity to another instead of having two apps?

Comment: @drexxx are you trying to make app locker for android applications???

Comment: is two app its what i want to do, looking on a way to do it

Comment: @drexxx you can launch another application from you application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `startActivityForResult()` to get the result from another activity.

By the help of android `startActivityForResult()` method, we can send information from one activity to another and vice-versa.

```
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,Class2.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent,10);
```

Comment: will try this one!

Comment: Inside your setOnClick method

Comment: @BibeshManandhar what is 10??

Comment: The 10 is not necessary. Also using 'this' is not a good practice. The proper way to do this is startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), class2.class)); Keep in mind this will only work if you have two activities in the same app and not two different apps.

Comment: I think he wants the picture back to the ImageView so using startActivityForResult need two arguments. so i used 10. and btw this was just an example so i used this. :)

Comment: Yeah all the suggestions worked find, I actually did a bit of research and you can actually use this lines too:

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                         Screen.class);
                    startActivity(intent);